# center the div absolute using css but i cannot figure out why its not moving to centre

Tags: css, css-float

i need to make a div position absolute and make it in center but i used does not make it happen. i have gone crazy trying to make it to the center. 
i have tried using left and right value to 0. it should have made the div to the center automatically.
need to figure out what went wrong?

help please!

here is the code that i have tried and stuck

```
.slider-wrap {
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 100px;
    background: #096; 
    z-index: 99; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle, it will be more helpful to understand your problem

Comment: `left`, `right` and `top` probably won't work without the `position: relative` or `position: absolute` style, is the slider-wrap block? try adding the `display:block` and delete the left and right attribute from your css

Comment: or at least your html structure

Comment: make your .slider-wrap as position:absolute and made it parent class as relative position

Comment: and also on which browser are you testing that? cause on fiddle this css is working

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the position to absolute

```
 .slider-wrap {
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px; 
    left:0; right:0; 
    top:100px; 
    background:#096; 
    z-index:99; 
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Add `position:absolute;`

```
 .slider-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px; 
    left:0; right:0; 
    top:100px; 
    background:#096; 
    z-index:99; 
    margin:0px auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to center a div is as such:

```
.slider-wrap {
...
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Also note that `z-index` will not work unless you set the `position` attribute. ie: `position: absolute;`

Comment: `DIV` it's a `block` element... It has no margin (100% by default) unless you set the a specific `width` to the block... Then something like `margin: 0 auto` will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: absolute;` to your css for absolute positioning.

Note: Also add `position: relative;` to the *parent* element you whish to use as wrapper.

So for example:

```
.slider-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}

.slider-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

*The width and height of 100% is optional, just added it in case you want the container to take up the whole remaining space or the whole page if it's right after the opening body tag...*

To position the slider-wrap in the center of the screen (so both horizontal and vertical centered), try this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slider-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}

.slider-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px; // half the height
    margin-left: -500px; // half the width
    ...
}
```

If you're able to make the slider-wrap display inline with e.g. `display: inline-block;` (keep browser support in mind with this one), then you could use the following instead:

```
.slider-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    text-align: center; // this one makes the slider-wrap center horizontally
    ...
}

.slider-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px;

    vertical-align: middle; // this one does the vertical centering
    ...
}
```

Another option is using `display: table-cell;`. It's about the same as the previous one:

```
.slider-container {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    text-align: center;
    ...
}

.slider-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px;

    vertical-align: middle;
    ...
}
```

Also `line-height: ?px;` will make vertical centering possible. But I think this answer is long enough now :-P

**Give it a try.** Fiddle around with this until you're happy with the result :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work fine.

display:block;